# Subreport Data Source Expression for XML document

Tags: xpath, jasper-reports

I'm trying to get a subreport working for a report using an XML document as a data source.

When I'm sorting main report data, subreport won't have to requery the XML document. Its expecting a *JRSortableDataSource*, not a *JRXmlDataSource*.

What am I doing wrong?

I used following datasource expression:

```
$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/person/phone")
```

The stack trace:

```
Error filling print... Error evaluating expression :      Source text : $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}.subDataSource("/person/phone")

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression :  

    Source text : $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}.subDataSource("/person/phone")     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:203)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:591)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:559)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluateExpression(JRFillElement.java:966)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:384)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:286)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:259)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:459)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2044)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:778)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:288)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:151)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:126)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:464)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:300)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:757)     
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:1003)     
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)     
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997) Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
No signature of method: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.SortedDataSource.subDataSource() 
is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [/person/phone]     
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:54)     
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)     
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)     
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)     
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)     
at TestParam_1362739351228_895383.evaluate(calculator_TestParam_1362739351228_895383:223)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:190)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your datasource expression `$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/B/C")`
Has a syntax error
You missed unmatched character at first `(`
Then

If its expecting a `JRSortableDataSource`
Use this expression
`((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRSortableDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("DefineThat")`

If its expecting a `JRXmlDataSource`
Use this expression
`((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("DefineThat")`

Comment: I really used $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}.subDataSource("/person/phone"). I sorted the main report by name... after that I've an error just like this. I don't know how to solve this error. If you don't mind, please explain me step by step. Because I'm a new Jasper Report user. Thanks.

Comment: You must cast `$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}` parameter to (`JRXmlDataSource` type) then your datasource expression must be as  
`((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/person/phone")` NOT `$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}.subDataSource("/person/phone")`

Comment: I already changed just like this. But error still occur. And also I used filter expression in subreport by passing parameter from main report. At this time, phone no is shown only one. I want to show many of the phone no. that person possessed. This filter is not work for me. I don't know how to do. If you know another way, please explain me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("Xpath")

when somebody uses the above expression to connect to create sub report in Jasper using XML Datasource we need to set the Report Language as groovy instead of Java .I think subdatasource is not a method defined in Java but in groovy .I'm trying to find a method which is equivalent to above in Java

Comment: 1.Click on Subreport or List or Table element 2.Go to Datasource Under Use a JRDatasource expression use the below expression((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)
  $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("Subquery Xpath") for Java

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, found this solution at the jaspersoft-community:

Capturing the original data source in a parameter:

```
<parameter name="MyDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

same in iReport-GUI:

- create new paramater at the main report
- Name: "MyDataSource"
- Parameter Class: "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"
- Use as a prompt: No
- Default value Expression: "$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}"

Now using the MyDataSource Parameter at the subreport-datasource:

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{MyDataSource}).dataSource("/Subreport/path")]]></dataSourceExpression>
```